# Slow POST after resetting BIOS

Tags: bios, post

After I did a BIOS reset (by taking out the CMOS battery and putting it back in), every time I boot now, POST takes ages. Not necessarily the POST itself, but it will stay stuck on "Loading Operating System..." for upwards to 10 seconds.
I didn't even get that screen before the reset.

Now this happened a long time ago already, but never really bothered me. I purchased a SSD now, and I boot into Windows in a few seconds, but the POST is slowing me down. I've tried the "Quick Boot" option in the BIOS, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Motherboard: Gigabyte P55-UD2

BIOS: Award

Any ideas?

Comment: The POST is the firmware that activates prior to the OS.  If you cold boot, how long until the Press F2, Press F12 key disappears?  That's the POST time.  Everything after where Windows starts to load until the desktop is ready is the OS time.  How did you load the SSD- did you clone or do a brand new install?  If your POST time is okay and your Windows load time is slow and you cloned the SSD, I'd guess you changed something like your SATA hard drive config - set non AHCI mode or RAID mode or something.

Comment: Well this is the order: the boot screen (press DEL to enter BIOS etc) - POST screen (checking for devices) - Loading Operating System screen - Windows boot screen. The POST & Loading Operating System (especially the second one) takes the longest.

Comment: @TutorialPoint: Is the OS drive the first boot device? It's possible the order got reset when you reset the BIOS, and now it's waiting for other devices before it finally moves on to the OS drive.

Comment: That might be it actually - I have my CDROM drive set as my first boot device. I'll try making the SSD the first boot device and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks so much! My POST is still the slowest part of my booting sequence, but it's much better now. If you put an answer down I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @karen Looks like you nailed it, perhaps add as an answer?